# How to have a raw sql in sqlalchemy column_property?

Tags: python, postgresql, datetime, sqlalchemy, timezone

So I have a model `Event` and I want to create a `column_property` called `start_time_local` which should be the `datetime` in the timezone which is stored in the column `timezone_name` and of course the datetime in UTC is stored in `start_time`.

So if,
`start_time is datetime(2014, 12, 3, 10, 00)` and
`timezone_name is u'Europe/Helsinki'` then,
`start_time_local` should be `datetime(2014, 12, 3, 12, 00)`

Well of course in SQL this was possible by executing something like this:

```
start_time::timestamptz AT TIME ZONE timezone_name
```

Although in the case of SQLAlchemy I am not sure how to make this available through a `column_property` or an expression for a `hybrid_property`. I tried using `literal_column` to execute this as a raw SQL and that didn't work out as it gave an error saying that it couldn't find the columns `start_time` and `timezone_name` when they do in fact exist. So I suppose that isn't very useful here. I also tried to find any functions but all of those that were related to time and timezone only seemed to convert between UTC and system time which isn't very useful to me.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this using `literal_column`. You just need to make sure to use the full column names (eg. `events.timezone_name`) and label the `literal_column`.

Here's an (untested) example:

```
class Event(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'events'
    start_time = ...
    timezone_name = ...
    start_time_local = column_property(
        literal_column("""
            events.start_time::timestamptz AT TIME ZONE events.timezone_name
        """), type_=DateTime).label('start_time_local')
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding upon the previous answer (which should get credit since it lead me to this answer). The parentheses and type_ were slightly off. this example should work

```
class Event(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'events'
    start_time = ...
    timezone_name = ...

    start_time_local = column_property(
        literal_column(
             """events.start_time::timestamptz AT TIME ZONE events.timezone_name""",
             type_=DateTime
        ).label("start_time_local")
    )
```

I utilized the above answer for a similar problem

```
class Attachment(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = "attachments"
    id = Column(UUID(), primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, )

    data = Column(BYTEA(), nullable=True)
    text = Column(Text, nullable=True)
    file_name = Column(String(255), nullable=True)
    content_type = Column(String(255), nullable=True)
    model = Column(String(255), nullable=False)
    model_id = Column(UUID(), nullable=False, index=True)
    meta_data = Column(JSON, nullable=True)
    deleted = Column(BOOLEAN, default=False)

    # return a data url when the attachment is an image
    image_url = column_property(
        literal_column("""
            CASE
                WHEN content_type LIKE 'image%' THEN 'data:image/gif;base64,' || encode(data, 'base64')
                ELSE null
            END
            """, type_=String).label("image_url")
    )
```